# Why has the data.table tag just been renamed r-data.table?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

It seems the [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) tag has just been renamed to [r-data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-data.table). Was this intentional and if so why?  We're not aware of any discussion in advance.  We rely on this tag a lot and have published links to it (which have just broken).

Comment: **No more comments.** Post answers - they're a hell of a lot easier to read and update. The tl;dr here is that a moderator merged the tags - you'll have to wait for his input if you're curious to know *why*. It doesn't matter though; merges are irreversible. Propose suggestions for going forward via answers.

Comment: This is the main reason I don't use merges anymore.  And that's all I really have to say about this here, since my comments keep getting deleted.

Comment: I'm seeing the tags on questions back to [tag:data.table] but the URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-data.table`. Should we expect this to change at some point? Is the change incomplete? Or am I just seeing the effects of caching somewhere? (Apologies if I am being impatient!)

Comment: @GavinSimpson: I think the caches just need to catch up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Many thanks from me too!  URLs are back to data.table now.  All that's missing is the tag wiki.  Will that be restored?

Comment: @MattDowle: I recovered the Tag Wiki from the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have seen quite a few tagging debates in my time, and as a result have grown rather disillusioned with the tagging system in general.

Arguments for how to properly use/name tags inevitably descend into multiple competing lines of argument with almost no clear answer. It's no better than arguments about the best way to name variables/classes/etc. I don't care what perfect system you have mapped out in your head about how to consistently name all tags across all languages. It's hopeless.

I've settled into an attitude of simply letting sleeping dogs lie unless there is a *significant* problem. Is the tag *actively* causing *significant* confusion? No? Then **leave it alone**.

Sure, the tag might not exactly fit into whatever naming convention you find most aesthetically pleasing. But if it's *working*, let it be.

The [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) tag was working just fine. It should have been left alone. (And it should be put back the way it was, if possible, which it looks like has now happened.)

Comment: I have no beef with the `data.table` tag, at all. I absolutely favour pragmatism, so this answer has my vote.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: That's what is mostly missing from this whole discussion: *pragmatism*. And note that as Shog9 states: the deed is done, tags have been **merged**, an action that cannot be undone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's *not* the impression Bill the Lizard gave when commenting earlier. If that *is* the case, what are we all discussing when there is football on the box? :-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson: see the [comment on the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260463/why-has-the-data-table-tag-just-been-renamed-r-data-table/260489?noredirect=1#comment42354_260463). But yeah, this is a bit of a storm in a glass of water, IMO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I saw that. Should I trust Shog more than Bill on this? :-) And whilst the merge may be irreversible, retagging everything that is currently [tag:r-data.table] back to [tag:data.table] and deleting the `r-data.table` synonym would solve this, no?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: I am not sure how much Bill was aware as to what had happened to the tag. If Shog says it was merged, then the tag was merged. If *all questions* now tagged `r-data.table` can be retagged as `data.table` instead, then it is reversible; and it looks this is actually being applied as we speak.

Answer (score 18):

Naming tags along the lines of [r-data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-data.table) is completely redundant and doesn't solve the problem of other similarly named R packages requiring similar tags in the future. In addition it is bad form to combine multiple independent bits of information or data within another a single entity as it makes it more difficult to nest concepts.

Consider Pandas, which has data frames that are modelled after the R data structure. It is far better to tag Pandas data frame questions as [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) and R-related data frame questions as [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) as this enables people a way of addressing [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) **only** when their issue is more generic than the specific implementations in R or Pandas. If Ruby were to get a data frame data object, the whole thing would scale nicely, as it would with Julia and their data frame-like data objects.

Renaming tags `language-topic` makes it far more difficult for users to engage on the generic `topic`.

(Note that the above example for [data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.frame) requires that tag wiki to be updated to be less R-specific, but that is far easier and better than wholesale retagging, merges etc.)

Comment: This is really *the* compelling reason *not* to do this. I expect to see [tag:python-2.7-pandas-data.frame] in the near future.

Comment: The rename was *likely* to completely disambiguate `data.table` from `datatable` (burninate) from `datatables` (which in real use == `jquery.datatables`), *not* to isolate `data.tables` to be an R-specific thing (even though it mostly is, for now).  Unfortunately unless the diamond mod that did the merge speaks up, this is only speculation.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is a bad change that shouldn't have been made without a discussion in the first place and should be reversed now.

First the case why it should be and was called `data.table` to begin with. The reason is very simple - this is the convention for **all** other R packages. Some examples are [zoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoo), [dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dplyr), [xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xts) etc. Calling it something else needlessly distinguishes it from every other R package.

Now the concern that a lot of people seem to have is that this can be confused with a generic term "data table". However this simply doesn't happen (as evidenced by absence of people mistagging their generic questions with `data.table`), and the reason is fairly simple. There are two other tags called [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) and [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables), which are the **first** thing to come up when types either "data table" (with a space) or "datatable" (without a space), and in fact `data.table` doesn't even appear in those lists. So one **has to** add a deliberate dot to get the `data.table` tag and since there is really nothing else programming related that's called `data.table`, it's clear why there are no mistagged questions and/or any confusion.

Comment: But there *have* been instances of confusion as a result of the use of the tag, some examples of which Bill has provided.  Consistency at the expense of tag clarity is absolutely not worth it.  Consistency in this context has very, very little value.

Comment: @Servy no example of confusion over the `data.table` tag was ever provided

Comment: I can appreciate that you right now have a very neat situation; all `r` tags are prefix free. That is *not* enough of a reason to *not* use use a prefix *in the case a tag is otherwise ambiguous* however. Note that I am not discussing wether or not `data.table` was causing confusion, just that your argument is not very compelling.

Comment: @Servy There has been no evidence of confusion over the use of [tag:data.table].

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is [this type of setting](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatable/info) *that* bad? Is tagging them as `[language] [language-keyword]` the only best option out there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand your point - if there is no case that the tag is causing confusion, why would one want to do this (unless it's done uniformly across *all* R packages)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `data.table` *isn't* ambiguous; we have no evidence of people tagging question as such when they mean the .Net or JQuery thing. We have very little evidence of people using `datatable` incorrectly along side r - when they do they are using the very generic term data table for a "spreadsheet"-like table of data. I suppose we should also be disambiguating [tag:datatable] and [tag:datatables] then?

Comment: You're not helping your case by continuously arguing an "if one should be disambiguated, they all should" straw man.  You're the only one making that assertion.

Comment: if there is no ambiguity to begin with (and there is 0 evidence of one), then i think it's clearly all or none situation

Comment: @Arun: I am discussing the argument against using a prefix *in general* here, not the `data.table` tag specifically. I would never follow the [`requests` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request), but I *do* follow the `python-requests` tag; I have no interest in all the other ways the `request` tag could be used (or `requests`, plural, could be mis-applied). I see no reason to apply things *across all `r` tags*, not when autocompletion is so effective to find the tag for you. Purity is not going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Only in so far as pointing out that the perception of a problem doesn't exist in this instance, but it does in other very related tags. If this change is allowed to stand, chaos could ensue if people then followed the precedent and suggested other things be merged, changed etc. How *would* you disambiguate [tag:datatable] now that it is used for several concepts (as per their wiki)? We have to see this issue here more generally; messing with an R tag used by a modest number of people is not too bad, but messing with all of [so]. The precedent is the issue here.

Comment: Rumors of the tag system going to hell are highly exaggerated, in spite of the efforts of a few high-rep pedants to overhaul it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that highlights an infelicity in the way one subscribes to topics. It would be better if you could follow questions tagged [tag:python] **+** [tag:requests] whilst someone more generally interested in [tag:requests] could just follow that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: But that's not how it works *now*. Within the current system, the *pragmatic approach* is to use prefixes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps, but once the precedent is set there is little to stop these things happening in the future. People do seem to be taking the side of: *Sorry this happened, it probably shouldn't, but is the end result not too bad now we've fixed the synonym?* And if this we just an R thing, perhaps that'd be OK. But more broadly, this sets a bad precedent and I would urge people to think beyond this being just an R (or whatever language issue).

Comment: Maybe if the Blame Game card wasn't played so early and so heavily...

Comment: @MartijnPieters again perhaps, but your desire to use tags to better manage subscribing to topics may not be a good way to organise things, as I mentioned in my Answer. We aren't going to please everyone, but forcing us to stick with this solution because it is easier to leave things as they are now (after a damaging edit) isn't a good way to handle this. Revert the change, *then* have this discussion more broadly, when those interested from a range of other tags can contribute.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed, but we must accept that it is galling to have the rug pulled from under your hard work (not mine, but I know the people involved in the "community" around the [tag:data.table] package) with no notice, just because someone decided to do it. We need to get past that of course, and not let those feelings (on both sides) cloud the real issue here. In one sense Shog's deletion of comments probably helped there.

Comment: @eddi I don't think this helps. Would knowing who did it change anything? No. Other Mods and people here have said this, in their opinion, shouldn't have been done without discussion. Let's leave it at that and focus on the constructive aspects of the discussion to find a good solution to the situation we now find ourselves in.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I didn't mean to say someone should say they did it (as you correctly point out, that's irrelevant, at least for me), I just meant someone should fix it - and it looks like someone did :)

Comment: actually a bit confused about current situation - questions show up with `data.table` tag now (great!), but, when you click on it, on the right side (or in the search box) it says `r-data.table`...?

Comment: @eddi See Robert Harvey's comment on the Question. May take a while for all this to work itself through.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 12):

The main argument *for* keeping this change seems to be that `data.table` tag is ambiguous.

My point of view is that it's very clear that many programming languages will have exact or similar keywords for same / similar concepts/data structures or quite different. But that's not a reason to keep prefixing it with the language.

It's exactly why the language itself is available as a tag. I find the scenario for `datatable` tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatable/info) much more reasonable. The tag clearly explains what it means with regard to each language. Now, one could search for `datatable` questions pertaining to `.NET` tag with `[.net] [datatable]`.

Another point is: assume that someone else develops a new R-package with the name `datatable` (note the missing `.`). Now, this would also be confusing with the existing `datatable` tag. And therefore it'll get a `r-datatable` tag. And the confusion still remains between `r-data.table` and `r-datatable`.

All in all, I don't think tagging with `[Language-keyword]` is such a nice  solution. I'm not arguing on ambiguity. It exists. But in my view, the use case I'v explained above seems a better alternative than `[language-keyword]` construct.

HTH

Comment: I largely agree with this; prefixes are necessary when a keyword happens to coincide with multiple, vastly-different *concepts* but trying to preemptively namespace everything is an exercise in frustration. If you can easily disambiguate a tag by combining it with another tag, *problem solved.*